# applying partial function on a tuple field, maintaining the tuple structure

Tags: scala, functional-programming, partialfunction

I have a `PartialFunction[String,String]` and a `Map[String,String]`.
I want to apply the partial functions on the map values and collect the entries for which it was applicaple.
i.e. given:

```
val m = Map( "a"->"1", "b"->"2" )
val pf : PartialFunction[String,String] = {
  case "1" => "11"
}
```

I'd like to somehow combine `_._2` with `pf`and be able to do this:

```
val composedPf : PartialFunction[(String,String),(String,String)] = /*someMagicalOperator(_._2,pf)*/
val collected : Map[String,String] = m.collect( composedPf ) 
// collected should be Map( "a"->"11" )
```

so far the best I got was this:

```
val composedPf = new PartialFunction[(String,String),(String,String)]{
        override def isDefinedAt(x: (String, String)): Boolean = pf.isDefinedAt(x._2)
        override def apply(v1: (String, String)): (String,String) = v1._1 -> pf(v1._2)
      }
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the magical operator:

```
val composedPf: PartialFunction[(String, String), (String, String)] = 
  {case (k, v) if pf.isDefinedAt(v) => (k, pf(v))}
```

Another option, without creating a composed function, is this:

```
m.filter(e => pf.isDefinedAt(e._2)).mapValues(pf)
```

Comment: This looks like a nicer way of doing what I did, I was looking for something more generic, perhaps even ootb in the standard library. Thinking about it,lenses might do the trick.

Comment: I understand, I also tried to find something ootb without success. I doubt there is something, because you would either need to compose functions of completely different types: `(String, String) => (String, String)` and `String => String`, or kind of "nest" one function in the other which is what my example does. Either way, I can't even the signature of such combining function would be hideous.

Comment: accepted the answer. I'll update here if I find a neat way to achieve this with lenses.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in Scalaz, that does exactly that: `second`

```
scala> m collect pf.second
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> 11)
```

This works, because `PartialFunction` is an instance of Arrow (a generalized function) typeclass, and `second` is one of the common operations defined for arrows.

Comment: would it still work if pf was a PartialFunction[String,Date]?

Comment: @EyalFarago Sure. `second` converts an arrow `A => B` to an arrow `(T, A) => (T, B)`. So it would convert `PartialFunction[String, Date]` to a `PartialFunction[(T, String), (T, Date)]`. If you use `pf.second` directly in `collect`, then Scala can figure out that `T` is `String`, but in more complex cases you may have to specify `T` explicitly, e.g. `pf.second[String]`.